# Convert String Object to Jackson in Java

Tags: java, jackson

Is it possible to turn the "=" sign into Jackson when creating the object? I have one String object like this

```
[NameObject{Key1='Value1', Key2='Value2'}]
```

output must be

```
"[NameObject{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"}]"
```

Comment: "=" convert to ":"?

Comment: So you have a String `[NameObject{Key1='Value1', Key2='Value2'}]` that you built yourself? Why don't you build it in a way that you already have the output format instead of building it in another way and then converting it?

Comment: Take a look at `replaceAll` method of `String` class.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve? Do you realize that the ouput you specified is not JSON?

Answer (score -2):

```
String jacksonObject = stringObject.replaceAll("=",":");
```

this should replace all "=" characters with ":" characters.